# How to vue watch a specific property in an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i want watch  " clientFilter " in array

TableProduit: [
              {
                  nr_commande: 0,
                  date_creation: "",
                  id_delegue: "1",
                  clientFilter: "" }
            ],

Comment: Please add the code you've already tried, so we can help you out from what you already have

Comment: Create a computed property that returns just the `clientFilter` from all array items using `Array.prototype.map()`. Then watch that computed property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example of what Terry proposed in the comments, using [a computed property and a watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). This always reads and writes from/tro the first element in the `TableProduit` array - you might need to make use of [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in order to get the correct object having a `clientFilter` property depending on your needs, but it's not clear what you're trying to achieve exactly from your question.

Type in the input field to change the `clientFilter` property and see the console message triggered by the watcher.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `<input type="text" v-model:value="TableProduit[0].clientFilter" />`,
  data: {
    TableProduit: [{
      nr_commande: 0,
      date_creation: "",
      id_delegue: "1",
      clientFilter: ""
    }],
  },
  computed: {
    clientFilter: {
      get: function() {
        return this.TableProduit[0].clientFilter;
      },
      set: function(newValue) {
        this.TableProduit[0].clientFilter = newValue;
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    clientFilter: function(newValue) {
      console.log(`clientFilter changed to "${newValue}"`);
    }
  }
});
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Constantin Groß : thank you so much for your help , it's working